# "Buffer full" exception

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, sockets, naudio

I'm trying to create application that sends and receives audio. I have 2 
BufferedWaveProvider's.

For the first one I do

```
private void AsioOut_AudioAvailable(object sender, AsioAudioAvailableEventArgs e)
{
    float[] sourceAudio = new float[e.SamplesPerBuffer*e.InputBuffers.Length];
    e.GetAsInterleavedSamples(sourceAudio);
    float[] proccesedAudio = new float[settings.BufferSize];
    byte[] result = new byte[settings.BufferSize*4];
    byte[] sendingAudio = new byte[e.SamplesPerBuffer*4];

    for (int j = 1, q = 0; j < sourceAudio.Length; j += 2, q++)
        proccesedAudio[q] = sourceAudio[j];

    //...audio is beeing proccesed by VSTHost...

    result.CopyTo(sendingAudio,0);

    if (connection.IsConnected)
        Task.Run(() => connection.Send(sendingAudio)); //Proccesed audio sends by socket
    inputAudioBufferedWaveProvider.AddSamples(result, 0, result.Length);
}
```

For the second one I do

```
private void AudioReceiving()
{
    while (isAudioReceiving)
    {
        incomingBytes = connection.AudioReceiving(); //Socket receives bytes
        incomingAudioBufferedWaveProvider.AddSamples(incomingBytes, 0, incomingBytes.Length);
    }
}
```

Those 2 BufferedWiveProvider's is mixing by the MixingSampleProvider.

```
mixingProvider = new MixingSampleProvider(WaveFormat.CreateIeeeFloatWaveFormat(Convert.ToInt32(settings.SampleRate), 2));

mixingProvider.AddMixerInput(inputAudioPanningProvider);
mixingProvider.AddMixerInput(incomingAudioPanningProvider);
mixingProvider.ReadFully = true;

asioOut.InitRecordAndPlayback(new SampleToWaveProvider(mixingProvider),2,Convert.ToInt32(settings.SampleRate));
```

After 3-4 minutes after starting application I get exception (Buffer full). I think problem with buffer that being filled by bytes received from network.

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You're constantly creating new buffers. So you probably need to release the buffers. Is there a contra function for .`AddSamples(`?

Comment: Who is generating the Buffer full exception the full Exception Type Name should give you a clue. Look at the stack trace, if you can - is it coming from `connection.Send()` ? This appears the most likely culprit to me. Other candidates are the `AddSamples()` method.

Comment: @Übercoder, `connection.Send()` method sends the audio signal. That one come from soundcard input, then that samples are added to the `inputAudioBufferedWaveProvider` by `inputAudioBufferedWaveProvider.AddSamples(result, 0, result.Length)`.